# Way to change the style of the selected "td" in the angular material table

Tags: angular, uitableview, angular-material

I am trying to change the style of "td" in the angular material table, when it's clicked. Style is anything like background color, padding, something like that.

I have tried including (click) on 'td' element. But, it's not working.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="userlist" (click)="this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';"><span><strong>{{element.name}}</strong></span> <br/>
         </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you please produce a stackblitz or something? Reproduce it so that we can debug it

Comment: @srikha please see my answer, and suggest changes if any. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To change the style of `mat-row` you need to override the `.mat-row` in your global `style.css` like below.

```
.basic-container .mat-row  {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding:5px;
 /* add more style to customize */
}
```

**[Here is solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-custom?file=styles.css)**

Hope this will help!

Comment: I have to make some changes in the css when that particular element is clicked in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `tabindex="1"` to the `mat-cell`

```
<mat-cell tabindex="1" *matCellDef="let element">
                    {{element[column.name]}}
                </mat-cell>
```

Now, on Clicking styles can be visible using following

```
mat-row.mat-row.ng-star-inserted mat-cell:active,
mat-row.mat-row.ng-star-inserted mat-cell:focus {
  background: tomato;
  color: white;
}
```

**[Stackblitz Demo showing change in td color when clicked](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-custom-td-change-onclick?file=app%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html)**